# Disable permissive SELinux setroubleshoot browser notices?

Tags: selinux

I'm running CentOS 5.4 with SELinux in permissive mode. I still get setroubleshoot browser notices in the taskbar. How do I turn these off without fulling disabling SELinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uncheck the setroubleshoot applet (`seapplet`) in `gnome-session-properties`.